# Entrada no if() mas as instruções não são executadas

Tags: c, if, processo, posix

Estou a tentar fazer um chat usando pipes(chat entre servidor e cliente). Fiz uma condição de saída, caso o server queira sair/desligar o chat escreve "quit", no cliente da mesma forma. Fazer "quit" a partir do servidor está a funcionar, no entanto apartir do cliente não. O meu código é este:

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "fifo.h"

int main()
{
    int readfd, writefd;
    umask(0);
    if((writefd=open(FIFO1, 1))<0)
        printf("client: Erro a abrir write fifo\n");
    if((readfd=open(FIFO2, 0))<0)
        printf("client: Erro ao abrir read fifo\n");

    char name[20], mensagem[200], OtherName[20];
    printf("Bem-vindo ao chat!\n");
    printf("Introduza o seu nome: ");
    fgets(name, 20, stdin);
    printf("Introduza quit caso deseja fechar o chat\n");

    if(fork()==0)
    {   
        while(1)
        {
            fgets(mensagem, 200, stdin);
            printf("\n");
            if(strncmp(mensagem, "quit", 4) == 0)
                exit(0);
            write(writefd, name, 20);
            write(writefd, mensagem, 200);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            read(readfd, OtherName, 20);
            read(readfd, mensagem, 200);
            printf("\n%s -->%s\n", OtherName, mensagem);
        }
    }

    close(readfd);
    close(writefd);
    if(unlink(FIFO1)<0)
        printf("client: não foi possível fazer unlink\n");
    if(unlink(FIFO2)<0)
        printf("client: não foi possível fazer unlink\n");
    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "fifo.h"

int main()
{
    int readfd, writefd;
    umask(0);
    unlink(FIFO1);
    unlink(FIFO2);//unlink dos fifos anteriores
    if((mknod(FIFO1, S_IFIFO | PERMS, 0))<0)
        printf("Erro a criar o fifo\n");
    if((mknod(FIFO2, S_IFIFO | PERMS, 0))<0)//criação de fifos
        printf("Erro a criar o fifo\n");
    if((readfd=open(FIFO1, 0))<0)//abrir o fifo em modo de leitura
        printf("Erro ao abrir read fifo\n");
    if((writefd=open(FIFO2, 1))<0)//abrir o fifo em modo de escrita
        printf("Erro ao abrir write fifo\n");

    char name[20], mensagem[200], OtherName[20];
    printf("Bem-vindo ao chat!\n");
    printf("Introduza o seu nome: ");
    fgets(name, 20, stdin);//nome do user no chat
    printf("Introduza quit caso deseja fechar o chat\n");

    if(fork()==0)//se fork()==0, então o server vai receber uma mensagem
    {   
        while(1)
        {
            read(readfd, OtherName, 20);//lê o nome do outro user
            read(readfd, mensagem, 200);//lê a mensagem do outro user
            printf("\n%s -->%s\n", OtherName, mensagem);//escreve a mensagem
        }
    }   

    else//se o servidor vai enviar uma mensagem
    {
        while(1)
        {
            fgets(mensagem, 200, stdin);//user introduz a mensagem
            printf("\n");
            if(strncmp(mensagem, "quit", 4) == 0)
                exit(0);
            write(writefd, name, 20);//escrever o nome para o pipe de escrita   
            write(writefd, mensagem, 200);//escrever a mensagem
        }
    }   

    close(readfd);
    close(writefd);     
    return 0;
}
```

No client.c, no seguinte if:

```
if(strncmp(mensagem, "quit", 4) == 0)
 exit(0);
```

O programa entra no if mas não executa instrução. Porque é que isto acontece?
Obrigado!

Comment: sera' que n~ao tem '\n' no final de mensagem? Desculpe, estou sem acentuacao no meu Linux.

Comment: como assim? não entendi @lemoce

Comment: Tem certeza que entra no if, tenta colocar um pause dentro do if... Acho que o lemoce quis dizer é que se a mensagem não esta " quit \n" esta indo com uma quebra de linha.. dai ele não esta entrando no if, pq a mensagem é maior.

Comment: já testei o if, ele realmente entra no if por isso não penso que o erro esteja aí @MatheusFrancisco

Comment: @Gazelle, o lance 'e que voc^e tem dois processos. O pai e o filho. O processo pai vai esperar at'e o filho terminar, s'o que o filho est'a dentro de um loop infinito. N~ao tenho certeza, mas voc^e tem que mandar uma mensagem de fim para o processo filho. Vou fazer uns testes.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz um exemplo mínimo:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t myPid = 0;

  if ((myPid = fork()) == 0)
    {
      printf ("processo pai %d\n", myPid);
      if (1)
        {
          exit(0);
        }
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("processo filho %d\n", myPid);
      while(1)
        {
          sleep(1);
          printf("mensagem do filho: dentro do while\n");
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Esse exemplo tem a saída:

```
macbook% ./a.out   
processo filho 2439
processo pai 0
mensagem do filho: dentro do while
mensagem do filho: dentro do while
mensagem do filho: dentro do while
^C
macbook%
```

Achei uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284325/how-to-make-child-process-die-after-parent-exits/36945270#36945270) no SO. Segue o exemplo mínimo baseado na resposta:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{

  // para testar o pid do pai apos o termino do pai
  pid_t ppid_before_fork = getpid();
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid == -1)
    {
      perror(0);
      exit(1);
    }

  if (pid)
    {
      printf ("processo pai %d\n", pid);
      sleep(10);
      if (1)
        {
          exit(0);
        }
    }
  else
    {
      // do comando $ man prctl
      // Return  the current value of the parent process death signal, in
      //   the location pointed to by (int *) arg2.
      int r = prctl (PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);
      printf ("processo filho %d\n", pid);
      while(1)
        {
          sleep(1);
          printf("mensagem do filho: dentro do while\n");
          // if que testa se o pid do pai esta diferente
          // ocorre apos o exit
          if (getppid() != ppid_before_fork)
            exit(1);
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Basicamente, o exemplo do colega se baseia na [especificacão](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01) posix:

> The parent process ID of all of the existing child processes and zombie processes of the calling process shall be set to the process ID of an implementation-defined system process. That is, these processes shall be inherited by a special system process.

Com uma citacão do autor da resposta:

> Traditionally, the system process adopting all orphans is PID 1, i.e. init - which is the ancestor of all processes.

Resumidamente, todo o processo orfão tradicionalmente recebe pid 1, pois ele é o ancestral de todos os processos.

Mais uma citacão do autor:

> Note that storing the parent process id before the fork and testing it in the child after prctl() eliminates a race condition between prctl() and the exit of the process that called the child.

Armazenando o processo pai antes do fork e testá-lo apos o prctl() elimina o *race condition* entre o prctl() e a saída do processo que chama o filho.

ps1: info do $ man prctl

> This call is Linux-specific.  IRIX has  a  prctl()  system  call  (also introduced  in  Linux  2.1.44  as irix_prctl on the MIPS architecture), with prototype

Pode não funcionar nos Unix